# FileDownloader - different behavioral which depend on browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, vaadin

On start, I try to describe the context. I have a button which on click return file with data from relevant days. When button is clicked I make query(with dates from-to) to DB and parse data to proper format, and return as `StreamResource` to `FileDownloader`. All classes are from `Vaadin` packages.

```
    Button btExport = new Button("Export");
    FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(getReportsStream());
    fileDownloader.extend(btExport);
    //update resource to download on click 
    btExport.addClickListener(event -> {
        fileDownloader.setFileDownloadResource(getReportsStream());
    });
```

All works fine in Chrome and IE browser. In Mozilla Firefox isn't. In Firefox browser, always return the old `StreamResource` object. Always return the same file, it's looks like Firefox take from the kind of cache, because in log I don't find the event click for Firefox, any action. In Chrome and IE logs are present.

All browser are up to date. `Vaadin` version: 7.7.6

Do You have an idea why it happens? Or maybe what can I make in a different way to achieve downloading file?

edit///

I found solution, but I don't know if it is temporary. After reinstalling browser it's strange behavioral no longer occur. If it's working fine by several days I will take it as solution.

Comment: You don't need to add the click listener to your button, the fileDownloader.extend(btExport) should be enough.

Comment: @Chris M it's enough when data as `StreamResource` are not changed dynamically(without refresh page). In my case, as I wrote, data was changed depending on chosen dates, so I must, on button click, input 'fresh' data as `StreamResource`.

Comment: Server side click listener will run after the download starts, not before.
The best workaround I know is to override `FileDownloader.getFileDownloadResource` or `FileDownloader.handleConnectorRequest` and have your stream generation logic there

```java
public Resource getFileDownloadResource() {
    setFileDownloadResource(getReportsStream());
    return super.getFileDownloadResource()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm testing on Firefox 49, after I install Firefox 57, but nothing change. Only when I clean cache and each remains it looks like it works. I check on another computers and works on version 57 and no works on version 49.

The conclusion is to have up to date browser and be sure to uninstall the old version of browser and clean up.